# Pagination query returning duplicate records for different page index

Tags: jpa, pagination, duplicates, recordset

**I am implementing pagination using JPA+EclipseLink+Oracle and nativequery
while querying i am setting proper values for 
query.setFirstResult();
query.setMaxResults();**

But in result-set i found duplicate records with previous fetched records for different page index.

```
               Query query = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from View");
                query.setFirstResult((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize);
                query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
                return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Can you write code snippet.

Comment: Added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Add order by like

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from View v order by v.id");
query.setFirstResult((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize);
query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
return query.getResultList();
```